# GCM: Retry-After header

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

According to [GCM documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) we can have a result message of this type:

```
{ "multicast_id": 216,
  "success": 3,
  "failure": 3,
  "canonical_ids": 1,
  "results": [
    { "message_id": "1:0408" },
    { "error": "Unavailable" },
    { "error": "InvalidRegistration" },
    { "message_id": "1:1516" },
    { "message_id": "1:2342", "registration_id": "32" },
    { "error": "NotRegistered"}
  ]
}
```

The second message has error type `Unavailable` and should be resent. According to documentation we should honor the `Retry-After` header if it's included in the response from the GCM server.

I have two questions:

1. Is the `Retry-After` header always available? Also in responses with status `200`?
2. Is actually possible that only one message should be resent as in this case? Should I resend only this message or all the bulk?

Answer (score 2):

1)

It's hard to say. On one hand, they say that `Retry-After` should be expected when you get errors in the 500-599 range :

> 5xx
>
> Errors in the 500-599 range (such as 500 or 503) indicate that there
>   was an internal error in the GCM server while trying to process the
>   request, or that the server is temporarily unavailable (for example,
>   because of timeouts). Sender must retry later, honoring any
>   Retry-After header included in the response. Application servers must
>   implement exponential back-off.

I examined the response headers both for the plain text request and the JSON request, and I didn't get a `Retry-After` for `200` response. However, I don't know how to simulate `Unavailable` error, so perhaps they do send that header if this error appears in the response.

2)

If only one message got the "Unavailable" error (as in your example response), then only that message should be resent. The rest of the messages either were successful or failed with errors that don't require a retry. Therefore they shouldn't be resent.

Comment: according to documentation the timeout happens when the HTTP status code is between 501 and 599, OR when the error field of a JSON object in the results array is Unavailable....so my guess is that you will have the header in the 200 response..but as you said there is no way to test it.

Comment: @user601836 But `Retry-After` is only mentioned in the context of 501-599 HTTP status code.

Comment: not entirely true. Look at http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html part about Timeouts